# how to fullscreen windows form in visual studio 2017 (c++)

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, c++-cli

I am still new to Visual C++

I am using Visual Studio 2017. How do you make the screen of a form fullscreen and be in the center? Supposing I have the following code

```
private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

}
```

Comment: If it is "full screen" then it is always centered.  Just set the form's WindowState property to Maximized in the designer.

Answer (score 1):

```
private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    CenterToScreen();
    FormBorderStyle = Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::None;
    WindowState = FormWindowState::Maximized;
}
```

CenterToScreen() - Centers the window in the screen

FormBorderStyle - Removes the Task Pane with the minimize, maximize and close buttons

WindowState - Screen is set to fullscreen

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.